# How to print items with the same number at index [0] in Python

Tags: python, indexing

For a program, I have a file with tons of different numbers. I need to create a program that will only print the numbers that start with 1. I have this so far:

```
f=open('filename.txt').readlines()
    for line in f:
        numbers=line[0]
        print(numbers)
```

which, of course, will continually just print the first number of each line until it has went through the whole document. I have tried

```
numbers=line[0]
if numbers==1
    print(number)
```

but that didn't get me anywhere. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some example data?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file, the contents will be a string or a bunch of strings. You can use string methods such as [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
f=open('filename.txt').readlines()
    for line in f:
        numbers = [x for x in line if x.startswith("1")]
        print numbers
```

The above code picks out all items in the string that start with `"1"`. However there is a problem since we do not know how your data looks like (e.g what the delimiters are), it's only ever going to return a bunch of ones. That's because it goes through the line byte per byte and as they are strings, it's impossible to know if 1 followed by a 0 is 10 or a 1 and a 0.

Here's a version that assumes your data is delimited by a `,`, I'm sure you'll figure out how to modify it to suit your needs.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    numbers = []
    for line in f:
        numbers.extend(x for x in line.split(",") if x.startswith("1"))
    print ", ".join(numbers)
```

The above code uses the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)-statement which you should use when dealing with files as it handles the opening and closing of the file descriptor so you won't have to. It then iterates over the lines of a file and adds each number to a numbers list if they start with a `1`. Finally it prints the numbers as a long string, delimited by `,`.

Demo data:

```
['3786, 9481, 314, 5951, 2676, 2938, 7725, 8849, 1609, 3451',
 '9036, 4079, 4718, 2180, 6609, 8864, 5391, 9663, 9431, 665',
 '6873, 2564, 559, 154, 573, 9232, 3094, 6530, 7594, 8347',
 '7150, 7889, 2108, 4278, 4362, 7282, 3784, 1943, 3655, 4335',
 '7196, 3537, 691, 5544, 70, 7171, 7375, 2911, 4992, 6834',
 '8298, 4905, 2366, 3368, 4474, 5900, 5506, 250, 1854, 4595',
 '4302, 3781, 984, 1176, 9183, 152, 9976, 2088, 9391, 8562',
 ......
 ]
```

Example output:

```
'1609, 154, 1943, 1854, 1176, 152, 1884, 1091, 1507, 1550, 1565, 1938, 1341, 1829, 1050, 1796, 1931, 1116......'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('filename.txt').readlines()
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == '1':
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbers = line[0]
if type(numbers) == int and numbers[0] == 1:
    print(numbers)
```

Hope this helps!